# XML Layout is different from emulator

Tags: android, xml

I have spent 4 hours to resolve this issue but I couldn't solve it Please any help would be appreciated. As I update my android studio this issues stuck in my android studio. I am using android studio latest version 3.2.1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".View.First_Screen">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/firstScreen_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/snap"
        android:src="@drawable/black_transparent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstScreen_buttonLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/firstScreen_image"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/firstScreen_login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:text="Login" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/firstScreen_register"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:text="register" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstScreen_connectDriver"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/firstScreen_buttonLayout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Or be a captain of uber"
        android:textColor="#311B92"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

[Here is attached image where you can see the difference of layout on both devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRBVd.png)

Comment: There's nothing wrong in the code... What's the screen size of the emulator?

Comment: I don't know but I happens only with updated android studio. On the old android studio every thing was fine. should I install back old android studio ?

Comment: but it happens*

Comment: That is an issue caused by lower DPI. That has nothing with Android Studio. You built your UI by referencing on particular screen size of one device. You didn't consider different DPIs.

Comment: It looks normal to me. Your emulator has a lower software DPI than the design preview.

Comment: No, don't reinstall. I think it's the emulator screen size which is bigger than the layout size, Nexus 4. Try to check on another Nexus devices or preferably on a real device.

Comment: I am confused. As I was doing the same stuff on the older version It didn't happen. I get the exact layout as shown on the emulator I don't know why happening with this latest android.

Answer (score 0):

First I would like to confirm which emulator you are using, is it nexus 4 or some other emulator, because in the preview your screen is selected nexus 4 and the view is shown for devices that has the same pixel density and resolution as nexus 4,
Next you have given a fixed height in dp to your ImageView with id - "firstScreen_image". that fixed height i.e. 350dp will behave differently for different devices.
So next question what do you want your screen to look like and how can I help?

Comment: Once I heard that dp adjust the things according to the screen size. I want the layout look exactly same on th left side emulator.

Comment: ok , first we need to know that emulator is which device?, is it nexus 4 or some other device.

Comment: I have tried with others too :) but the result is different on the real device.

Comment: you can use the library like this - https://github.com/intuit/sdp, it provides units in sdp instead of dp, using sdp help you build more similar screens for different devices.

Comment: or altogether you can use remove the height given in fixed dp and use weight instead.